# Get the value of an IntInsnNode using ASM

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to get the value of an IntInsnNode using the ASM (Bytecode) library.
The IntInsnNode instuctions are below:

```
 sipush 18998
 bipush 91
 bipush 34
```

So what I'm trying to achieve is getting the 18998, 91 and 34.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
It can be done using the `operand` from IntInsnNode class.